# Updating an xsl:variable in an .xslt file using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have an .xslt file with just a few variables in it. I need to update two of them using Powershell. The file looks like:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:variable name="VarA" select="this data stays the same" />
    <xsl:variable name="VarB" select="this data also stays the same" />

    <xsl:variable name="ChangeMe_1" select="data to be changed" />
    <xsl:variable name="ChangeMe_2" select="more data to be changed" />

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I need to update the select values in the variables named ChangeMe_1 and ChangeMe_2 to parameters passed into the Powershell script. I'm a total newbie at Powershell, and I'm finding lots of resources on parsing XML files, but this xslt is just different enough that it's confounding me.

Additionally, this needs to be done in every .xslt file with the same name in a hierarchy of folders, so if anyone can point me in the right direction for that I'd very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, I suggest to test it in a test folder before run it in production:

```
param ($path, $filename, $newvalue)

$files = dir $path -filter $filename -Recurse
foreach ($file in $files)
{
[xml]$xml= gc $file.fullname
$xml.stylesheet.variable | ? { $_.name -match 'ChangeMe_[1|2]' } | % {$_.select= $newvalue }
$xml.Save($file.fullname)
}
```

Comment: Perfect, completely does the job. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

treat your file as xml :

```
[xml]$t=@(gc C:\temp\test.xslt)
$t.stylesheet.variable | ?{$_.name -like "ChangeMe_1"}|%{$_.select="New Value"}
$t.Save("newname.xslt")
gc .\newname.xslt

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:variable name="VarA" select="this data stays the same" />
  <xsl:variable name="VarB" select="this data also stays the same" />
  <xsl:variable name="ChangeMe_1" select="NewValue" />
  <xsl:variable name="ChangeMe_2" select="more data to be changed" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The save doesn't seem to work - that last line fails and tells me it can't find "newname.xslt" and indeed, it's not there.

Comment: try to specify complete path `$t.save("c:\temp\newfile.xslt")` I've tested both in V2 et V3

Comment: Yay! That worked, but ultimately I need the path to be dynamic - this needs to be run on an entire folder hierarchy, updating all files anywhere in the hierarchy with the same name, and the root folder will change as well. Any ideas?

Comment: try : `$files=ls $mypath  -Filter "*.xslt" -Recurse; $files |%{ [xml]$t=(gc $_.fullname) ... }`

Comment: Now it's asking me for parameters, like so: 

cmdlet ForEach-Object at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Process[0]:

Comment: replace the "..." in my previsous comment with the code provided in my answer above.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I of course did that, should have mentioned it. Still get the parameter prompt.

Comment: m'y internet connexion died will check @home